# Fill in the Dashes : Part 1 of 10

Tags: english, knowledge

This is part of the [Fill in the Dashes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Fill%20in%20the%20Dashes%22) series of puzzles.

Example : F_ in the B_  Fill in the Blanks

Can you identify the idiom(s)/phrase(s) from english language ?

1) It t_ T_ to T_

2) O_ in a B_ M_

3) B_ a_ the b_

4) The W_ N_ Y_

5) W_ u_ the b_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*<del>Note that this is a partial answer...</del>* Completed [with a little help from my friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBDF04fQKtQ)

1.

> It takes two to tango.

2.

> Once in a blue moon.

3.

> Beat around the bush.

4. Credits to Aggie Kidd...

> The whole nine yards.

5. Credits to Aggie Kidd..

> Water under the bridge

Comment: 2. Once in a blue moon

Comment: 5. Water under the bridge.

Comment: @CodeNewBie You all rock !!! Way to go !!!

Comment: 4. Whole Nine Yards

Comment: @AggieKidd: Go ahead and post the two you've cracked in a separate answer. You deserve an upvote, mate!

Comment: 3. could also be Beauty and the beast.

Comment: @user3294068: And it could even be [Baillie and the Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie_%26_the_Boys), but both this and Beauty and the Beast cannot be classified as idioms in the English language. Looking at the theme, beat around the bush is a better fit.

Answer (score 10):

Following CodeNewbie's request (all credit to CodeNewbie for the full answer):

> 4. The **W**hole **N**ine **Y**ards
>  5. **W**ater **u**nder the **b**ridge

Answer (score 3):

3 could also be

> Beauty and the beast.